# "En" en français

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, pronoms, en

Je n'ai jamais vraiment compris quand on doit utiliser le pronom "en" en français. Je sais que ça correspond avec la préposition "de" d'une manière ou d'une autre, mais par exemple, il y a cette phrase:

> La population de la Grèce est 10 millions.

Donc, on devrais être permis de remplacer "de la Grèce" avec "en" mais ça n'a rien de sense:

> La population en est 10 millions.

Donc, où est ma faute ici et qu'est-ce que je devrais me souvenir de ce pronom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> La population en est 10 millions.

est possible, quoique peut-être pas très courant. Dans un contexte où l'on a déjà parlé de la Grèce, on pourrait très bien y faire référence de cette façon. Attention: il faut bien que la Grèce ait été mentionnée précédemment. Si la phrase est isolée, elle n'a effectivement pas de sens, car on ne sait pas à quoi ce *en* se rapporte.

Les pronoms remplacent des noms, des groupes nominaux, et parfois des propositions, mais seulement si l'objet auquel on se réfère est évident d'après le contexte.

Une tournure beaucoup plus courante serait:

> La Grèce est un pays méditerranéen. **Sa** population est ...

Voici un graphe de Google ngrams pour des données numériques sur les fréquences d'utilisation, au moins dans le corpus écrit de cet outil:

[image]

Comment: Je crois que ceci fonctionnerait sans nommer le pays et **en** y faisant seulement allusion: “Il existe sur les bords d’une mer aux décors merveilleux un pays à la culture millénaire, berceau de la philosophie telle que la comprend le monde moderne. Pourtant, malgré l’ampleur de cet héritage fantastique, ce n’est qu’un tout petit état: la population n'**en** est que 10 millions.” Je fends peut-être les cheveux en quatre, cependant...

Comment: @Feelew - but I think that although you are not naming the country, the context really builds up to that _en_: there is the word _pays_ earlier, and it is then heavily qualified, which makes that _en_ completely non-ambiguous. So the context would be what makes this work. Très bon example de l'importance du contexte, en fait :-)

Comment: Je cherchais des poux et croyais **en** avoir trouvé une mine. Je suis sans doute trop facétieux et superficiel pour ce site, mais l’esprit analytique de ses participants m’**en** guérira sûrement bientôt, à grand renfort de mises au point!

Comment: De mieux **en** mieux :-) J'espère que Luke verra ces examples et saura **en** faire l'analyse **en** détails et **en** temps voulu. L'intérêt de cette discussion pourrait **en** dépendre, ou peut-être pas.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is this "en" okay?

I personally agree with your "n'a rien de sens" feeling. I'm not sure this use of *en* is the most natural.

> La Grèce est un pays. La population en est de 10 millions.

To my intuition the *en* replaces: "10 millions *de quoi* ?" rather than "la population *de la Grèce*".

Similarly:

> Il y a quelques biscuits. Beaucoup en sont à moitié mangés.

This doesn't feel right to me either. Something about the *en* immediately following the noun that the *de* phrase would otherwise qualify is awkward. It's certainly the placement and not the type of phrase; after all, this clearly makes perfect sense:

> La Grèce est un pays. Je veux en savoir la population.

But perhaps the placement is more okay than you and I feel. This has plenty of hits in Google searches, Ngram searches, and other resources:

> La cause en est évidente.

Here *en* clearly replaces "la cause *de ce phénomène*".

I would be interested in a way to disambiguate these cases (or see more that are the same as the Grèce one to rid me of an incorrect intuition!).

---

#### Are there better ways to say this?

As others have suggested, there are some more natural-feeling ways to express your original sentence:

> Greece is a country with a population of ...
>
> La Grèce est un pays d'une population de ...

Or using *dont*:

> Greece is a country whose population is ...
>
> La Grèce est un pays dont la population est ...

Or using a possessive:

> Greece is a country; its population is ...
>
> La Grèce est un pays. Sa population est ...

---

#### Are there more natural uses of "en"?

> Voici quelques biscuits ! Je veux en manger. = I want to eat *some of them*.
>
> Voici du pain ! Je veux en faire un sandwich. = I want to make a sandwich *out of it / with it*.
>
> Voici un monstre ! En as-tu peur ? = Are you afraid *of it*?
>
> Sa femme passait devant lui et il ne s'en est aperçu. = He didn't catch sight *of her*.
>
> Passe la nuit chez lui, puis tu peux en partir. = You can set out *from there*.
>
> Va-t'en. = Get away *from here / from me*. (Implicit; this is a fixed verb *s'en aller*.)
>
> Notre équipe a marqué un dernier but, et nous en avons gagné. = We won *as a result of that*.

Comment: Ah bon? J'aurais dit que c'était la population du pays, que _en_ = _of it_ here. Je suis surpris. "_En_" est bien présent dans l'index du LBU, avec de multiples emplois et expressions - mais je n'ai pas encore trouvé quelque chose d'applicable au cas présent.

Comment: Je trouve dans LBU des exemples tels que _Vous voulez des renseignements? Je vous **en** donnerai_, _je vous **en** donnerai un bon_, _vous êtes émue, je m'**en** aperçois_.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think those are quite the same. *Je vous en donnerai"* : the *en* refers to a partitive *de*; *Je m'en aperçois* : the *en* refers to the *de* of *s'apercevoir de*. It's this genitive (?) sense "The population of Greece" that I think I'm balking at. But I'm starting to wonder now. Will think about this and update/delete answer soon...

Comment: Je crois qu'il y a pas mal à dire sur ce petit _en_ :-)

Comment: A more evenhanded and fleshed-out revision, coming right up...

Comment: You found _La population en est **de** 10 millions._ which I also thought about, and which sounds a bit more natural, so you have some familiarity with this phrasing :-) _Beaucoup en sont à moitié mangés._ sounds more incorrect, or possibly this **en** would refer to the cause, to what ate them, as in _ils **en** sont atteints_, talking about a disease. I am starting to wonder if the _en_ in the initial sentence is not trying to mimic the (correct): _Je veux **en** savoir la population._

Comment: @Frank I'm never 100% sure about when to use *de* before a number, but I noticed that this phrase is similar to "Le taux est de [chiffre]", so imitated it. Also jlliagre's answer. :p

Comment: Your intuition about the pronoun would align with mine — that if the *en* is indeed valid, it's because it refers to some unknown complement to *mangés* or *10 millions*, not to the complement of *la population*. But some of the *La cause en est évidente* examples that turned up couldn't be read any other way than as a complement to *cause*. So I wonder if that's a fixed phrase, or a subtly different structure, or if my intuition is incorrect... I'm reading @jlliagre's answer as reflecting a similar uneasiness about this *en*...

Comment: I'm not really uneasy about this _en_, and ngrams turned up examples of _la population en est_. I wouldn't really have stopped if I had read or heard it. It's only when thinking more about it that it becomes a bit mysterious.

Comment: “_Beaucoup **en** sont à moitié mangés_” est étrange pour moi aussi. Il me semble qu’une cause à la disparition partielle des biscuits (ou peut-être un autre type d’information complémentaire) serait requise. Peut-être quelque chose comme “_Les fourmis ont trouvé l’entrée de la boîte à biscuits. Beaucoup de son contenu **en** est grignoté_” (bon! j’évite ici la moitié mangée, parce que bien que rapides à ce genre de tâche, les fourmis me semblent un peu petites).

Comment: I can imagine many examples of *la population en est* appearing in Ngrams, but without context, how would we determine what the *en* replaces? @Feelew's intuition here backs up once more the notion that it's perfectly all right, but isn't the complement of what immediately precedes it. Also, good point... I suppose anyone, ant or no, who eats only half a cookie is probably grignoter-ing rather than manger-ing. :)

Comment: Yes - that is a problem with ngrams. Usually, you need to go verify a sampling of the examples the results are based on. But my intuition doesn't match with yours here - I can understand this _en_ only if it refers to _Grèce_. Interesting :-)

Comment: Interesting indeed. Then we need to find a basis for disambiguating that and the "beaucoup en sont" case where our intutions do align. :p I guess we've exhausted the scope of a comment thread, though!

Comment: Do you have access to the LBU? It talks a lot about that _en_, but I got lost in the details. Maybe I should go back over the weekend when I have time.

Comment: Moi non, il faut que j'en demande une copie pour mon prochain anniversaire ou bien m'efforce de faire l'investissement un de ces jours !

Comment: Oui, ça vaut le coup. Il y a aussi une version online maintenant, ce qui est peut-être une bonne idée, car cet ouvrage est touffu, et avoir de bons outils de recherche dans le texte est _très_ utile :-)

Answer (score 3):

La phrase :

> La population de la Grèce est 10 millions.

n'est pas idiomatique et probablement incorrecte. On dira plutôt :

> La population de la Grèce est **de** dix millions **d'habitants**.

Difficile de caser « en » ici.

Comment: Je suis d'accord, il manque quelque chose dans la première phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense qu'un bon exemple pour l'utilisation de "en" pourrait être:
"Tu as de la farine pour le gateau? Il en faut 300g".

Pour revenir à la question de la phrase sur la Grèce, on peut dire:
"La population grecque est de 10 millions."